# Add elements to 2D array in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create a two dimensional array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966225/how-to-create-a-two-dimensional-array-in-javascript)

I want to push elements to 2D array,

My code is,

```
        var results = [];
        var resultstemp = [];
        function bindlinks(aamt,id1) {
        resultstemp=results;        
            imagesArray.push($("#image1").mapster("get"));

            if(results.length==0)
            {
            results.push([id1]);    
            }
            else
            {
               var ck=0;
               var lng=results.length;
                for (var i = 0; i < lng; i++) {

                  if(results[i]==id1)
                  {

                    ck=1;
                     results = jQuery.grep(results, function(value) {
                        return value != id1;
                      });

                  }                                     
                }                   
                if(ck==0)
                {
                results.push(id1);                  
                }                   
            }
```

I want to push `id` as well as `aamt` to array. Here i am pushing only id to array. I am not sure about how to add `aamt` to second position in 2D array.

Help me please,

Thank you

Comment: is `var results = [][];` even a valid syntax?

Comment: no..that is not valid...my mistake

Comment: I'm somewhat confused as to what you want to do... Can you reword the question?

Comment: Can you please explain your end goal instead of just asking to fix the code?

Comment: So you want to push aamt and id1 evenly into a 2d array?

Comment: @DC_ In my code i am using 1D array and pushing id1. But i actually want to push both id1 as well as aamt. For that i need 2D array.. 1st position i want to save id1 and aamt in 2nd position

Comment: @esimov yes, i want to push both id1 and aamt evenly to 2D array

Answer (score 6):

Change the declaration as follows:

```
var results = new Array();
```

and change the `push` as follows:

```
results.push([id1,aamt]);
```

Hope it would help

Comment: This isnt working since push takes only one element. When i tried this code the values id1 and aamt is pushed to same position in 1D array separated by comma

Comment: That is how a 2D array will look like. :) Eg: `[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]`

Answer (score 0):

The logic behind the method to push two separate values in the same array evenly is something like this:

```
var array = [];
function push(id1, aamt) {
    for (var i= 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (i%2 == 0) {
            array.push(id1);
        }
        else {
            array.push(aamt);
        }
    }    
}

push(10, 12);
console.log(array); // 10, 12, 10, 12.....
```

Take note i abstracted the code quite a bit, because for me was not too obvious what the code should have to do, but the principle is simple: use the modulo (`%`) operator to test if the value is odd or even. If odd add the first value if even add the second value.

Hope it helps.